# Php Mailer gives error Insufficient system space(Error code:4.3.1)

Tags: php, linux, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I'm using phpmailer_5.2.1. While i try sending mail, i get an error "SMTP server error: 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage.". I checked my disk space and found /dev/sda is full. Do i need to free /dev/sda/ ? Am i on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there's an error because of storage in `/dev/sda/` it seems you have to make a bit space there..